# TensorFlow Object Detection API very innacurate

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am using the exact sample code on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb
I am trying to build a system to recognize bicycles or motorcycles. However, when I use one of my own photos(640x480)from my project the results are not good. Not only are most objects not detected ie bike, person, other cars, but the one car recognized is classified as a cellphone. For all the other example images (from google) I get the correct result (ie two dogs, persons, etc). Why is this happening and what can I do about it? 
￼￼[image]

Comment: What dataset is used to train the model that you are working with? If it is open images, you could check this line: `output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)` and change `np.uint8` to `np.int64`

Comment: I tried with ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 and ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28 but resutls were similar.

Comment: Have you tried every time with the same "kind" of images (all taken from drone/security camera)? In coco dataset most of images are taken from different angle. Could you try those models with other images (more similar to coco) and check if it works as expected?